# Python equivalent for MySQL's IFNULL

Tags: python

Is there a function in Python that checks if the returned value is None and if it is, allows you to set it to another value like the `IFNULL` function in MySQL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not really, since you can't rebind arguments.

```
if foo is None:
  foo = 42
```

or

```
def ifnull(var, val):
  if var is None:
    return val
  return var

foo = ifnull(foo, 42)
```

Comment: The body of `ifnull()` could be shortened to `val if var is None else var`, also.

Comment: It can be shortened to `return var or val` actually

Comment: @IonutHulub: No, since lots of non-`None` values are false.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to convert all "falsy" values (i.e. `None`, `0`, `""`, `[]`, `False`, etc.) to a specific value and let everything else through untouched, you can use `or`. For example:

```
print (x or default_value)
```

will print the value of `x` if it's truthy, and the value of `default_value` if `x` is falsy.

I mention this because `IFNULL` is often used this way to clean up nulls in boolean and numerical columns in a database and so might be what you or others were after. Obviously, if you want to treat `None` differently to `0`, `False`, etc. this won't work.

Comment: This is a far better solution for those who don't want to have to evaluate something twice or save it to a temporary variable.

Comment: yes as you mentioned above, this method only work if you sure x is possitive or None. Otherwise negative x or 0 will also return default_value

Comment: @HarryDuong Negative isn't `False`.  Only zero is `False`.

Answer (score 12):

Like this:

```
x = SOME_VALUE if x is None else x
```

Answer (score 1):

`nvl(v1,v2)` will return `v1` if not null otherwise it returns `v2`.

nvl = lambda a,b: a or b

Comment: `a` also be `0` or `[]` or `{}` or `()` or `''`. For all of these `b` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL:

```
nvl(foo, bar) [or even nvl2(foo, baz, bar) in Oracle]
```

---

Using Python ternary operator (see detailed explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)) within a lambda function as follows:

```
nvl = lambda foo, bar: bar if foo is None else foo

nvl2 = lambda foo, baz, bar: bar if foo is None else baz


foo = nvl(foo, 42) # returns 42 if foo is null

foo = nvl2(foo, 7, 42) # returns 42 if foo is null or 7 is foo is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

We made this one:

```py
def d_nvl(d,key,default_val):
    try:
        return d[key]
    except Exception:
        return default_val
```

and it is used this way:
`my_val = d_nvl(my_dict,'my_key','default_val')`

Answer (score -1):

I'm using SQL Oracle, it has NVL() function which replaces null. For example, NVL(null,1) returns 1 and NVL(3,1) returns 3. Simple python equivalent for that function:

```
import numpy as np

nvl = lambda a,b: b if np.isnan(a) else a

nvl(3,1)
>>> 3
nvl(np.nan,1)
>>> 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -2):

Since this question is now over 2 years old I guess this is more for future references :)

What I like to do is `max('', mightBeNoneVar)` or `max(0, mightBeNoneVar)` (depending on the context).

More elaborate example:
`print max('', col1).ljust(width1) + '   ==>   '+ max('', col2).ljust(width2)`

Comment: Looks a little bit convoluted to me, and it's also worth noting that while comparisons like this work in 2.x, in Python 3.x, `NoneType` isn't orderable and thus you will get a `TypeError`